# Help me identify a chip marked `145AZ01 A2E1A53 C`

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, surface-mount

This is part of a 4 channel WiFi switch - most probably a resistive or capacitive touch controller. However, I am unable to find any reference online using marking from the chip (145AZ01 A2E1A53 C). Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be an R7FA2E1A53CFJ#AA0 ARM microcontroller. I just searched for the the second line of your marking.

https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/698/r01ds0386ej0130_ra2e1-2930932.pdf
Pinout on page 19.

You can test this by measuring the Resistance between Pin 1 and 7 when the device is turned off. If it's not near zero, you can rule this family of microcontrollers out.

Comment: It's the right controller, [lcsc.com](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Microcontroller-Units-MCUs-MPUs-SOCs_RENESAS-R7FA2E1A53CFJ-AA0_C3222419.html) has a picture and it matches.

Comment: Hans, Nanash - thank you both for helping out, much appreciated.